# Title Bar is empty in Kotlin If I click the Back Button

Tags: android, kotlin

If I click from Activity 1--2 then I am able to see the Title bar but If I click back from 2--1 then the Title bar value is empty. I tried onBackPressed method but still its not helpful. I tried shared preference and local file storage but Its not helpful.

```
    Model Class:
    class TestProject(val name: String,val location: String)

    Main Class:     
         private class ItemDetailAdapter(val TestProjectList:Array<TestProject>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemDetailViewHolder>()
        {

            override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ItemDetailViewHolder, p1: Int) {
                val TestProject=TestProjectList.get(p1)
                p0?.customView?.TestProjectName?.text=TestProject.name
                val TestProjectPicture=p0?.customView?.itemPicture
                Picasso.get().load(TestProject.location).into(TestProjectPicture)
    //Below code solved the Title Problem
                    p0?.Title=TestProject
            }
            override fun getItemCount(): Int {
                return TestProjectList.size

            }
            override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ItemDetailViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(p0?.context)
                val customView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.items_details,p0,false)
                            return ItemDetailViewHolder(customView)
            }
        }
        class ItemDetailViewHolder(val customView:View,var Title: TestProject?=null):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(customView)
        {
            companion object {
            val ITEM_TITLE_KEY="TestProject"
            }
            init {
                customView.setOnClickListener {
                    val intent= Intent(customView.context,TestProjectMenuList::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(ITEM_TITLE_KEY,Title?.name)
                    print("Printting Title :$Title?.name")
                    println("Hello Test $ITEM_TITLE_KEY")
                    customView.context.startActivity(intent)
                    println("Test")
                }
            }

TestProjectList Class:
val navBarTitle=intent.getStringExtra(MainClass.ItemDetailViewHolder.ITEM_TITLE_KEY)
            supportActionBar?.title=navBarTitle
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that

```
val navBarTitle=intent.getStringExtra(MainClass.ItemDetailViewHolder.ITEM_TITLE_KEY)
```

...has a value, you can put

```
val navBarTitle=intent.getStringExtra(MainClass.ItemDetailViewHolder.ITEM_TITLE_KEY)
supportActionBar?.title=navBarTitle
```

inside the onResume function.

Comment: HI Rhylle, I tried that option already. If I go from A--B its working fine but If I click B---A then its empty.